# Minix write to the file from /kernel/system

Tags: kernel, minix

I need to write some information to my special log file (for example, `/home/log.txt`) from `kernel/system/do_kill.c` (Minix).

I already tried:

```
int filedesc;
filedesc=open("/home/log.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDWR);
write(filedesc, "Test message\n", 13);
close(filedesc);
```

but file doesn't appear. (But `printf()` displays text in the console).

Using `fprintf()` causes error while compilation (`make clean all` from `/usr/src/tools`).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the existing source to see how the kernel does logging

I'm pretty sure it uses logging.c : `log_init` and `event_log`

Comment: logging.h (to use log_init) doesn't exist in my minix :(